# how to connect to server

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

My application maintains a file name hyper link and clicking on the hyper link would display the file in a browser as it is an xml file. In my local machine i can read the files located at a particular location. Similarly when i deploy my application on a DEV server i would like the application to fetch the files from a path defined by me. My application runs on some xyz server and the files are residing on some abc server. How to connect to abc server from an application running on xyz server. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You'll have to write some code that uses the HTTP protocol to fetch the file from server abc. There's no reason why a server (xyz) can't play client.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the url of the file as you said then just this should do the work :

```
URL url = new URL("yoururl");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
String line;
     while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
      }
     in.close();
```

Comment: Thank you M.Sharma i tried the way you mentioned and got the following exception "java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: sftp". I searched for the exception and found that i need jsch to connect to a server using sftp.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my question. I am trying to connect to server using sftp protocol which makes me unable to use URL class. I used Jsch, an external jar and used the hostname, username and password to establish a connection and read files from a server that is different from which i am running the application on. Here is an example explaining the same
http://kodehelp.com/java-program-for-downloading-file-from-sftp-server/